# Create relation with existing nodes Cypher Neo4j

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, graph-databases, nosql

I am creating a relationship graph with unique Source's hashtag. I am wondering that is every time I have to check if source or target is already exists after creating nodes first time?

If I use Merge when source is exists but target is new then merge failed to create node. I want to create following graph.

I am using following code using JAVA

```
    String CQL = "CREATE (source:Source {hashtag: '1'})-[:TIMELINE {weight: 3, date: '1417132800'}]->(target:Target {hashtag: '2'})";
    ExecutionEngine execEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, StringLogger.DEV_NULL);
    ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute(CQL);
    String results = execResult.dumpToString();
    System.out.println(results);
```

Secondly please guide me how can I get json from **ExecutionResult execResult = execEngine.execute(CQL);** to create map in d3.js

Following CQLs I have to run.

```
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (label:Source) ASSERT label.hashtag IS UNIQUE

    // if source and target are new
    CREATE (source:Source {hashtag: '1'})-[:TIMELINE {weight: 3, date: "1417132800"}]->(target:Target {hashtag: '2'})

    // if source and target are already created and have another TIMELINE relation
    MATCH (source:Source {hashtag: '1'}),(target:Target {hashtag: '2'}) CREATE (source)-[:TIMELINE {weight: 15, date: "1417132200"}]->(target)

    // if source already exists but target is new
    MATCH (source:Source {hashtag: '1'}) CREATE (source)-[:TIMELINE {weight: 20, date: "1417133200"}]->(target:Target {hashtag: '3'})

    // if source is new but target already exists
    MATCH (target:Target {hashtag: '2'}) CREATE (target)<-[:TIMELINE {weight: 30, date: "1417133400"}]-(source:Source {hashtag: '4'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quite understand what you mean with

> f I use Merge when source is exists but target is new then merge failed to create node.

`MERGE` should be used in a minimalistic way. In case a single item of a path specified in `MERGE` is not found, the *whole* pattern is created. That said, if you want to eventually create start node, end node and a relationship in between use

```
MERGE (source:Source{hashtag:'1'})
MERGE (target:Source{hashtag:'3'})
MERGE (source)-[:TIMELINE {weight: 30, date: "1417133400"}]->(target)
```

#### regarding your 2nd question: creating JSON

If you switch over your usage model to run a Neo4j server and use the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html), you get back JSON directly.

If you want to render JSON directly from Java code, use the usual suspects, e.g. [Google's GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: How can I run these three **MERGE** queries that you specify together with **execEngine.execute(CQL);** Currently if I run three queries separate with **execEngine.execute(CQL);**  then at last query it create relation with anonymous nodes. Here is a screen shot please have a look [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByeIpS6bnLocMWZnaWpncGloZFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: put all the three lines from above into one string and send it via `execute()`.